# Euclidean distance divided by square root of number of arrays?

Tags: euclidean-distance, angle-to-euclidean-space

I have come to learn that if I want to overally compare two vectors in my research, the best way is to use Euclidean distance divided by square root of number of arrays. However I don’t know what this equation is called. I will appreciate it if you can share your knowledge with me about that.

Thanks

Comment: By the "number of arrays" do you mean the number of dimensions of the vector?

Comment: Yes, I mean the dimension of the vector.

I found the answer to my question. that term is called "normalized Euclidean distance"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question. that term is called "normalized Euclidean distance"